# Check if user orders something

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to receive information if a user has ever bought something but with using JOIN?

I have this query with subquery

```
SELECT C.*,
(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ORDERS O WHERE C.ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID ) AS HAS_ORDER
FROM CUSTOMERS C
```

I tried this

```
SELECT C.ID, C.NAME, C.SURNAME, COUNT(O.ID) AS ORDERS_COUNT
FROM CUSTOMERS C
LEFT JOIN ORDERS ON C.ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY C.ID, C.NAME, C.SURNAME
```

But it has a poor performance than subquery and the point is that I cannot use subquery (ORM which I use cannot create subqueries)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. And for performance issues please include the execution plan using "Paste The Plan".

Comment: Those queries aren't really comparable. One returns a `1` if an arbitrary row is found, the other `JOIN`s to *all* the related rows and `COUNT`s the value of a column. If performance is poor, then I would suggest the *real problem* is the (lack of appropriate) indexing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.ID,C.NAME,ISNULL(X.ID,0)IS_ORDER
FROM CUSTOMER AS C
OUTER APPLY
(
   SELECT TOP 1 ORD.ID
   FROM ORDERS AS O
   WHERE C.ID=ORD.CUSTOMER_ID
)X
```

You can try to USE CROSS APPLY/OUTER APPLY to detect if customer has ordered something at all

Comment: I'm not sure the `ID` should be returned in the outer `SELECT`; an arbitrary `ID` is unlikely to have any meaning.

Comment: Can agree  with you, but if topic starter only wants to know if there were any order/orders (without any additional information about them) then this approach is quite possible, but may be not optimal. In the other case OUTER APPLY needs to be reworked.

Comment: I thinking more `CASE WHEN X.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`.